# Which ruby version is included in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, ruby

which ruby version is included in Ubuntu 16.04?

I couldn't check because I'm running a different OS at work.

Comment: On 16.04LTS:$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Answer (score 2):

Information about packages can be found online at [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

You can easily search a packages by putting its name at the end of the url: https://packages.ubuntu.com/ruby. Then you get a list with all packages with *ruby* in its name.

[Package *ruby* in Ubuntu 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ruby). Version 2.3.0.

Comment: The correct package is [ruby2.3 in xenial-updates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/ruby2.3), which shows the Apt version to be `2.3.1-2~16.04`. However, the correct way to get the actual version is to run `ruby --version`, which returns `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ruby is not installed

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-68-121:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
ubuntu@ip-172-31-68-121:~$ ruby --version
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby
```

Comment: Not by default. Nothing in the default install uses it, so it's not installed.